# Update table records randomly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'd like to change the order of the records randomly in the table. Is it possible? I'm using SQL Server 2016.

```
Example:
From that:
[UID] [Name]
54     Name1
24     Name5
8      Name6
50     Name7
19     Name10

to like that: (randomly)
[UID] [Name]
50     Name7
8      Name6
19     Name10
54     Name1
24     Name5
```

Note: These are two columns

Don't need to replace 100% of the records, it can repeat the same order sometimes like a lottery. I just need to mix them.

Comment: Although Gordon's answer is correct, this seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do that this activity is intended to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to change the order of the records randomly in the table. Is it possible?

No, this is not possible.  SQL tables already represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, although you can define columns that specify an ordering.  You can even cluster the rows based on column values, so the data is stored in order.  That does not mean it will be retrieved in order.

What you can do is to randomize when you query.  In SQL Server:

```
select t.*
from t
order by newid();
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL have Rand() which will order rows in random manner

try this query :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: You will find update functionality here : https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_rand-update.php

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to generate two row number sequences, one based on a fixed order and the other random.  Then, self join your table on the two sequences and do a random update of the name column.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UID) rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) rn_rand
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE t1
SET t1.Name = t2.Name
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn_rand;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function like this:

```
with 
  cte1 as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by newid()) rn
    from tablename
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by newid()) rn
    from tablename
  )
update c1 
set c1.name = c2.name, c1.UID = c2.UID
from cte1 c1 inner join cte2 c2
on c2.rn = c1.rn;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ae672bf24e1edf534f3e9c3a1e0f1de).

But interchanging randomly the rows is of no value because the physical order of the rows is not what you should care about. 
Always use an `ORDER BY` clause when retrieving the rows based on the existing columns or define a new column for this purpose.